Can two people buy a goat and sacrifice it on behalf of another person?
For the sacrificial offering of Eid Al-Adha what I know is the sacrificial offering can be done for only one person for smaller animals such as a sheep/goat. But can two guys buy an animal (probably putting in half of the money each) and sacrifice it on another person's name? For example, can two brothers buy a goat together and sacrifice it on behalf of their mother/father?
